# Custom post registration causing errors

Tags: custom-post-types

I copied this code from a youtuber. It works for him, but not for me. Does the code contain any errors? As soon as I put it in, my WordPress breaks and won’t load.

```
function gt_custom_post_type() {
  register_post_type('project',
    array(
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects'),
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Projects'
        'singular_name' => 'Project',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Project',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Project'
      ),
      'menu-icon' => 'dashicons-media-document',
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'supports' => array(
        'title', 'thumnail', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'comments'
      )
    )
  );
}

add_action('init', 'gt_custom_post_type');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many small problems with this code (see my comments below):

```
function gt_custom_post_type() {
  register_post_type('project',
    array(
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects'),
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Projects', // <- missing comma
        'singular_name' => 'Project', 
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Project',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Project'
      ),
      'menu-icon' => 'dashicons-media-document',
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'supports' => array(
        'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'comments' // <- thumbnail not thumnail
      )
    )
  );
}
add_action('init', 'gt_custom_post_type');
```

Also you’re lacking any internationalization in there...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using this resource for getting custom post type code to add to your functions.php: https://generatewp.com/post-type/ If you're finding that you're still running into errors after using that code, then the issue is likely how you're adding it to your functions.php file.

There's also a great plugin called Custom Post Types.